# How to get the splitting field of a polynomial?

Tags: group-theory, field-theory, galois-theory, splitting-field

I'm sorry if I sound too ignorant. I don't have a high level of knowledge in math.

While reading an article about Galois theory, I've become confused over the concept of a splitting field. The author defines the splitting Field of the polynomial $p(x)$ as the smallest field extension of $Q$ that contains all the roots of $p(x)$. He/She then gives the examples of $p(x)=x^2−2$, which splitting Field is $\mathbb{Q}[\sqrt2]$ since "it contains all the roots of $p(x)$ and if it had fewer elements it either wouldn't contain all the roots or wouldn't be a field" and that of $p(x)=x^4−5x^2+6$ which splitting field is $\mathbb{Q}[\sqrt 2,\sqrt 3]$, then the author decides to finish the paragraph by asking the question "Can you see why?".

And that is the issue, I cannot see why :/

I struggled for a while trying to think of a general method or explanation to why those field extensions correspond to those polynomials, but I couldn't come up with anything.

Any thoughts/ideas would be really appreciated!

Comment: Hint : $x^4-5x^2+6=(x^2-2)(x^2-3)$ , hence $\sqrt{2}$ and $\sqrt{3}$ are the positive roots.

Comment: The phrase "splitting field" of a polynomial refers to the factoring of the polynomial into first-degree polynomials, so "splitting" the polynomial in that sense.

Comment: Yup. But how can one prove that there exist no other field extension of Q smaller than Q[√2,√3] that contains the roots of  $x^4−5x^2+6$?

Comment: There are other fields that contain those roots, but the splitting field is the smallest one in a suitable sense.  If that is the point you are confused by, I'll try to find a previous Question that hits the point squarely or (in the alternative) post a new Answer here.

Comment: @Leo because it has to contain $\sqrt 2$ and $\sqrt 3$. Therefore, this field must have an element of the form $a + b \sqrt 2 + c \sqrt 3$. But $\Bbb Q [\sqrt 2, \sqrt 3] = \{ a + b \sqrt 2 + c \sqrt 3 : a,b,c \in \Bbb Q \}$

Comment: $\sqrt{2}$ and $\sqrt{3}$ are already roots of your polynomial, so splitting field must contain those, and the smallest field containing those is $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2},\sqrt{3})$, by the definition.

Comment: I can understand, for example,  why $Q[√2]$ is a field extension of $Q$, at the same time, I can see why $Q[√2]$contains the roots of the polynomial $x^2−2$. What I'm not able to get is how the author is so sure that $Q[√2]$ is the smallest field extension of $Q$ which suffices the latter statement. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Oh, by definition...I get it. But how could one prove that $Q[√2] = a + b√2$?

Comment: @Leo $Q[\sqrt 2]$ is by definition the subfield generated by $Q$ and $\sqrt 2$. Prove that $\{a+b \sqrt 2\}$ is a subfield containing $Q$ and $\sqrt 2$ and contained in every subfield containing $Q$ and $\sqrt 2$.